# Passing values to Controller via Javascript return View MVC3 Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am brand new to MVC.  I am trying to pass longitude and latitude values I obtain using geolocation to my controller so that I can use the values to identify and pull the correct data from my database.

Here is my Javascript

```
function auto_locate() {


    alert("called from station");
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_map);



function show_map(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    var locstring = latitude.toString() + "." + longitude.toString();
    var postData = { latitude: latitude, longtitude: longitude }
    alert(locstring.toString());

}

}
```

All of this works fine;

Now what I need to do is pass postData or locstring to my controller.  Which looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AutoLocate(string longitude, string latitude)
{
    new MyNameSpace.Areas.Mobile.Models.Geo
    {
        Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(latitude),

        Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(longitude)

    };


// Do some work here to set up my view info then...
    return View();
}
```

I have searched and researched and I have not been able to find a solution.

How can I call the javascript above from an HTML.ActionLink  and get the Longitide and Latitude to my controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("AutoLocate")',
    type: 'GET',
    data: postData,
    success: function(result) {
        // process the results from the controller
    }
});
```

where `postData = { latitude: latitude, longtitude: longitude };`.

Or if you had an actionlink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("foo bar", "AutoLocate", null, null, new { id = "locateLink" })
```

you could AJAXify this link like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#locateLink').click(function() {
        var url = this.href;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            var postData = { latitude: latitude, longtitude: longitude };
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                data: postData,
                success: function(result) {
                    // process the results from the controller action
                }
            });
        });

        // cancel the default redirect from the link by returning false
        return false;
    });
});
```